# xen installation on cent os 6.3

Tags: installation, centos, xen

I followed tutorial http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-xen-on-centos-6.2-x86_64-paravirtualization-and-hardware-virtualization

To install xen on Centos 6.3 everything is going perfect but, after editing /boot/grub/menu.lst

```
Quote:
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE: You have a /boot partition. This means that
# all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
# root (hd0,0)
# kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_xen-LogVol01
# initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sdb
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.32.57-2.el6xen.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /xen.gz dom0_mem=1024M cpufreq=xen dom0_max_vcpus=1 dom0_vcpus_pin
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32.57-2.el6xen.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_xen-LogVol01 rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_xen/LogVol01 rd_LVM_LV=vg_xen/lv_swap rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=128M KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
initrd /initramfs-2.6.32.57-2.el6xen.x86_64.img

title CentOS (2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_xen-LogVol01 rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_xen/LogVol01 rd_LVM_LV=vg_xen/lv_swap rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=128M KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64.img
```

when i reboot it is booted with xen kernel but when i run command

```
xm info or xm list
```

showing error

```
" Error: Unable to connect to xend: No such file or diectory. Is xend running "
when i run command

xend start
```

showing error

```
" xc: error: Could not obtain handle on privileged command interface (2 = No such file or directory): Internal error
xend/image.py: Error connecting to hypervisor "


ls /proc/xen


" ls: cannot access /proc/xen: No such file or directory "
added entry in /etc/fstab

Quote:
none /proc/xen xenfs default 0 0
```

after reboot gives error no such file or directory,

```
lsmod | grep -i xen output: Nothing...

modprob xen-evtchn

FATAL: Error inserting xen_evtchn (/lib/modules/2.6.32.57-2.el6xen.x86_64/kernel/drivers/xen/xen-evtchn.ko): No such device

modprob xen-gntdev

FATAL: Error inserting xen_gntdev (/lib/modules/2.6.32.57-2.el6xen.x86_64/kernel/drivers/xen/xen-gntdev.ko): No such device
```

I have enabled hardware virtulization in bios still problem not solved.

I tried another tutorial https://www.crc.id.au/xen-on-rhel6-scientific-linux-6-centos-6-howto/

it seems like nothing is working for me...

Guys... please share your thoughts about this problem...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i ran into this too in booting a Xen dom0 kernel.

i might have spotted one small omission in your grub.conf compared to the instructions.
in the grub config section at this line: "replace the first word initrd with module."

for example, here's my working Xen Dom0 grub.conf.

good luck!

```
default=0
timeout=2
title CentOS 6.3 Xen dom0
  root (hd0,0)
  kernel /boot/xen.gz loglvl=all guest_loglvl=all
  module /boot/vmlinuz-dom0-kernel ro root=/dev/sda1 nomodeset console=ttyS0,115200 iommu=off earlyprintk=xen initcall_debug debug loglevel=10
  module /boot/initrd-dom0-kernel.img
title CentOS 6.3 (No Xen)
  root (hd0,0)
  kernel /boot/vmlinuz-dom0-kernel ro root=/dev/sda1
  initrd /boot/initrd-dom0-kernel.img
title Stock CentOS 6.3
  root (hd0,0)
  kernel /boot/vmlinuz-centos6.3 ro root=/dev/sda1
  initrd /boot/initrd-centos6.3.img
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick!

Check your boot entries in grub. I just upgraded my Centos 6.3 with the kernel-xen-3.5.3-1 to 3.7.1-3 and the new boot entry for this kernel gets wrong because between updates I installed a standard kernel for testing other things.

Fixing the correct boot options for xen brings back my virtualization!

```
title CentOS (3.7.1-3.el6xen.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /xen.gz dom0_mem=1024M cpufreq=xen dom0_max_vcpus=4 dom0_vcpus_pin
        module /vmlinuz-3.7.1-3.el6xen.x86_64 ro root=UUID=<longUUID> KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet
        module /initramfs-3.7.1-3.el6xen.x86_64.img
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

> Could not obtain handle on privileged command interface (2 = No such file or directory): Internal error

This was solved by adding the below line in /etc/fstab

```
none /proc/xen xenfs defaults 0 0
```

See this post in the [Xen Project mailing list](http://old-list-archives.xenproject.org/archives/html/xen-users/2010-03/msg00510.html) for more details.